# I've never set up a cron job before but would like to run a Python script daily in 15 minutes on my server

Tags: linux, python-2.7, cron

I have a python script which prints the ip address of the server I want it to run in every 15 minutes how can I do it? 
I am a beginner so I know very less about cron job.
My code of the python script is:

```
import socket
import os

ipaddr = os.popen("ip -4 route show default").read().split()

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((ipaddr[2],0))
ipaddr = s.getsockname()[0]
print 'IP ADDRESS:',ipaddr
```

Answer (score 0):

Type following command
crontab -e

Write below line

```
#min hour day month weekday command
*/15   *    *    *    *     /path/to/your Python script
```

save it